# converting a static layout to % percentage layout using css

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have put together a simple static layout where I would lilke to understand how to convert the static widths into percentages in order to eventually create a responsive web layout. Can anyone recommend the easiest way to work out layout widths, font-sizes, padding and margins in percentages? I have been so used to creating my layouts in static format but I would love a complete understanding on how to implement this % technique.

Link to my simple layout is here: http://jsfiddle.net/9fH87/

All advice welcomed,
Thanks Kyle

Comment: You really should make a jsfiddle or a jsbin using that code so we can work with your code instead of making everyone who tries to answer use guesses as to what your code should look like

Comment: Is this what it's supposed to look like? This is using your code: http://jsbin.com/adasah/3/

Comment: There are whole books written on how to do this. Answering all those questions can't be done here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replacing the fixed width of the two columns with 45%, you'll get a fluid layout, it means a layout that fit it self to the container.
You can find tons of examples with [an easy search](http://www.google.com/search?q=fluid+layout+two+column+css+example).

Answer (score -1):

Honestly, percentages are a bad idea, because they correspond to how wide the viewport is all the time, if you resize the viewport closer together, all the words just squish together.

The best way to do it is to make a container div (name it body-container), give it whatever width you want, and center it using this code `margin: 0 auto;` then set the min-width of the body to something acceptable. 1080px is usually good since most people nowadays have a resolution at least 1080 wide.

Here is my example: http://jsbin.com/ufesif/2

Comment: hi mark, basically i want to achieve a responsive design eventually using media queries which I hope will prevent the 'shishing' you talk about by controlling my layout at different resolutions

Comment: Your layout works perfectly if you just add `min-width:1080px;` to the body. Here is the example: http://jsbin.com/ufesif (I used jsbin because that is better for working with layouts)

Comment: Using media queries is how to fix the concern over viewport size and is used in mobile applications all the time. That usage is now making its way to desktop browsers, too.